# sort value seperated by comma

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to sort two values a and b in ascending order and to get a_out and b_out from both of them

```
a= c("MN, OP, AB")
b = c("MN, O P, A B")
a_out = "AB,MN,OP"
b_out = "A B,MN,O P"
```

I have tried with the below statement but unable to get desired output

```
a_out = sort(a)
b_out = sort(b)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split sort and combine the string.

```
split_and_sort <- function(x) {
  toString(sort(unlist(strsplit(x, ',\\s*'))))  
}

split_and_sort(a)
#[1] "AB, MN, OP"

split_and_sort(b)
#[1] "A B, MN, O P"
```

To apply it on column you can use `sapply` -

```
split_and_sort <- function(x) {
  sapply(strsplit(x, ',\\s*'), function(x) toString(sort(x)))  
}

df$a <- split_and_sort(df$a)
```

Comment: a= c("MN, OP, AB","AP,MN,SS")
  b = c("MN, O P, A B","MN, O P,C  B")
  
  df = data.frame(a,b)
  df$a = as.character(df$a)
  df$b = as.character(df$b)
  df$a_out = split_and_sort(df$a)
  df$b_out = split_and_sort(df$b)

Comment: Perfect but Not getting the proper output when i ran on the dataframe

Comment: To apply it on dataframe use `sapply`, see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split the strings and paste them together with `strsplit` and `unlist`:

```
> toString(sort(unlist(strsplit(a, ",\\s*"))))
[1] "AB, MN, OP"
>
```

Or with `[[1]]` instead of `unlist`:

```
> toString(sort(strsplit(a, ",\\s*")[[1]]))
[1] "AB, MN, OP"
>
```